# Analytics Callback Fails on Firefox Private Browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser, callback

My project have analytics for this click function, and wait for the callback to navigate to next page. But on Firefox, private browsing prevent analytics trigger, since no callback not move in to next page. I can add a timeout to trigger move to next page. But I'm looking another best way to handle issue:

```
$('#NextPage').click(function() {
    sendGAEvent({
        category: 'NextPage',
        action: 'Move_NextPage',
        callback: function() {
            gotoNextPage();
        }
    });
});

function sendGAEvent(data) {
    try {
        ga('send', 'event', data.category, data.action, {hitCallback: data.callback});
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log('failed.');
        data.callback();
    }
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, apply formatting and see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you will get better response and save others time reading and answering you

Comment: You need to get more to the root of why private browsing is interfering with your function.  As it looks here, it's just a click event and a function call.  What is going on in `sendGAEvent()` that is different when private browsing?  Are you missing a cookie or local storage you need?  Right now, I'm thinking you would have to show us the code for `sendGAEvent()` if you want us to be able to help.

Comment: Firefox prevent triggering sendGAEvent()  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tracking-protection-pbm